# Associated laguerre polynomials for the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

The associated laguerre polynomial $L_k^N$ is a solution to the differential equation:
$$
xy'' + (N + 1 - x)y' + ky = 0
$$

For the reduced radial equation for the hydrogen atom, we know that the solution is:
$$
U_{nl} = r R_{nl}(r) = r^{l+1}f(r)e^{-\lambda r}
$$

where $f(r)$ satisfies:
$$
f''(r) + 2 \left(\frac{l+1}{r} - \lambda\right) f'(r) + \frac{2}{r} \left[ - \lambda(l+1) + \frac{\mu}{\hbar^2} \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} q^2 \right]f(r) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Making the substitution:

\begin{align*}
\rho &= 2 \lambda r = 2 \frac{\sqrt{-2 \mu E}}{\hbar} r &\lambda &= \frac{1}{na_0} & a_0 &= \frac{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 \hbar^2}{\mu e^2}
\end{align*}

where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius and the second equation can be found by substituting the quantized energy levels of hydrogen:
$$
E_n = -\left(\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\right)
     \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{\mu  e^2}{2 a_0}
$$

into the first equation.

(1) then becomes:
$$
\rho \frac{d^2 g(\rho)}{d \rho^2} + [(2l + 1) + 1 - \rho] \frac{d g(\rho)}{d \rho}  + \left[
 (n + l) - (2l + 1)
 \right] g(\rho)  = 0 
$$

So the solutions should be the laguerre polynomial:
$$
L_{(n+l) - (2l + 1)}^{2l+1} \tag{2}
$$

However, my textbook, which is "Quantum Mechaics: Concepts and Applications" by Nouredine Zettili, on page 358, states that the solution should instead be:
$$
L_{(n+l)}^{2l+1} \tag{3}
$$

Is (3) even correct? Shouldn't the solution clearly be (2)? I was suspecting some symmetry property of the laguerre polynomials such that:
$$
L_{k}^N = L_{k - N}^N
$$

But this is most certainly NOT the case, as we can see that, if we let $k = 5$ and $N= 2$ then:
$$
L^{N}_{k - N} = L^{2}_3 \neq L^{N}_{k} = L^2_5
$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction) has form (2) for hydrogen wavefunctions. Your textbook must be using a different definition of associated Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: @G.Smith You are right, they had use:
$$
L_n^m = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^m L_n
$$

instead of 

$$
L_n^m = (-1)^m \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^m L_{m+n}
$$

Thanks!!